# Events between Aura components and Canvas Apps

Tags: lightning-aura-components, canvas

We have a complex lightning page.  It contains an Aura component, and a separate Canvas app within a VF page.  We need:

1. the Aura component to send a message to the Canvas app
2. the canvas app to send a message to the aura component.

The dev guide for canvas seems to be saying that canvas apps can publish and subscribe to events to each other, but is what we need to do technically achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where [window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) can help you in delivering events, as this looks like cross-origin communication.

If you have control over the canvas app then you can use `postMessage` to publish message to your lightning domain and then write a `addEventListener` with `message` channel like this `window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {}` and the consume those events in Aura Component.